# Switch / Case to generate URL causes spaces

Tags: php, html

I am using a switch case method to generate the correct image URL for a websites icon.

```
  <div class="logo"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>
  <?php
    $url = home_url( '/' );
    switch ($url) {
        case "http://dx.zachryracing.com/es/":
            echo "/img/logo-spanish.png";
            break;
        case "http://dx.zachryracing.com/":
            echo "/img/logo.png";
            break;
    }
    ?>" alt=“Zachry Racing Logo” /></a></div>
```

My problem is that there are 2 spaces being generated in the URL:

`http://dx.zachryracing.com/es/wp-content/themes/boot_strap%20%20/img/logo.png`

for example.

This simpler form is working fine (without the dynamism):

```
<div class="logo"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/logo.png" alt=“Zachry Racing Logo” /></a></div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's the two spaces between: `<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>` and next opening tag, you should eliinate them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're overcomplicating this a bit. Try this

```
<img src="<?php
bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');
$url = home_url( '/' );
echo (stripos($url, '/es/') !== false) ? "/img/logo-spanish.png" : "/img/logo.png";
?>">
```

That should show the Spanish logo if your URL contains the `/es/` directory

Comment: Thanks, this is more maintainable.

Answer (score 3):

Between the stylesheet directory and the img folder you close and enter php and that's where you have the white space. `?>  <?php`

Try this:

```
<div class="logo">
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"
        ><img src="<?php 
            bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); 
            $url = home_url( '/' );
            switch ($url) {
                case "http://dx.zachryracing.com/es/":
                    echo "/img/logo-spanish.png";
                    break;
                case "http://dx.zachryracing.com/":
                    echo "/img/logo.png";
                    break;
            }
    ?>" alt=“Zachry Racing Logo” /></a></div>
```